# How to grant a user access to all stored procedures on mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I'm trying the following:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'my_user'@'%';
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pwd';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.* TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

but I get the error:

```
Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; please consult the manual to see which privileges can be used 0.000 sec
```

If I name a proc explicitly:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'my_user'@'%';
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pwd';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.my_proc TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

then it works fine, but I want to allow the user account to have access to every proc on the db, is there anyway to do this without explicitly granting permission to every individual proc?

Comment: Try this `GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'my_user'@'%';`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this instead, it will work:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

Comment: Is the difference between the query and the answer due to the fact that mydb.* is NOT a procedure but (possibly) many procedures ? Where is this mentioned in the manual?

Comment: @user2338823 exactly. If you try `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE` it expects a single procedure. My command grants execute permission for every procedure in the database.

Comment: Is this mentioned in the manual ? May I ask, how did you learn this ?